# my auto reply function is not working what could be the problem?

Tags: php, forms, email, post, send

im trying to send 2 mails with 1 form. The first mail should go to my personal email with the user data, and the second mail should got to the user email that I will be contacting him, this is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && $_POST['email'] !==''){

    if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['subject']) || 
        !empty($_POST['message']) || 
        filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
        $tel = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['tel']));
        $email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
        $m_subject = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']));
        $message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

        $to = "pepito100@gmail.com"; 
        $subject = "$m_subject:  $name";
        $body = "recibiste un nuevo email desde la pagina de Fácil Soft.\n\n"."detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nTelefono: $tel\n\n\nEmail: $email\n\nAsunto: $m_subject\n\nMensaje: $message";
  
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("mensaje enviado, gracias por contactarnos en breve nos estaremos comunicando");
            window.location.href="index.php";
            </script>';
    
        if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){ 
          $to = $email;
          $subject= "fácil soft";
          $body = "Hola".$name."gracias por contactarnos nos estaremos comunicando a la brevedad. Atte Fácil Soft";
    mail($to,$subject,$body);
        }else{
            http_response_code(500);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
error_reporting(0);

?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: What Operating System are you using

Comment: For the 2nd mail function , you are using `mail($email,$headerRep);`, (the 1st and 2nd parameters are `to` and `subject` respectively. The 3rd parameter is `message body` but you do not have this . ). so there is empty body and many mail servers will filter off such mail.

Comment: i would keep in  mind a better code identation, thanks

Comment: im using windows

Comment: @Ken Lee thank you i just changed the code and its working now

Comment: Great. Have a nice day.